# In Switzerland, is accident insurance legally required to have medical care vetted by a third-party doctor?

Tags: accident, switzerland, accident-insurance

I work in Switzerland, so I'm legally required to have accident insurance.  I had a bicycle accident about three months ago and sustained a few injuries, including an ongoing rotator cuff problem for which an orthopedic surgeon prescribed physical therapy.

Recently I got a letter from my accident insurance company saying they'd sent my MRIs to some other doctor, a doctor whom I've never seen, and this doctor ruled that I couldn't possibly have any ongoing effects from the accident.  Therefore, said the accident insurance, as of date XYZ they would no longer pay for medical care.

I have two questions about this:

1. Is this actually legal in Switzerland, to let such a decision be made by a doctor who's never seen the patient?
2. The insurance company talked as if the outside doctor's diagnosis was not merely *legal*, but in fact *legally required*.  Is it?